# How can I add rows to a dataframe with zero value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with product sales to different accounts. Some of our products we haven't sold to those accounts, but I need it included in the dataframe with a 0 value. Here is what I have:

| account | degree_type | discipline | dollars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harvard | 4 Year | Accounting | 1000 |
| Yale | 4 Year | Biology | 2000 |
| Ivy Tech | 2 Year | Biology | 500 |
| Harvard | 4 Year | Precalculus | 3000 |

Let's assume we've never sold Biology to Harvard. I need a dataframe that looks like this which includes Harvard Biology at 0:

| account | degree_type | discipline | dollars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harvard | 4 Year | Accounting | 1000 |
| Yale | 4 Year | Biology | 2000 |
| Ivy Tech | 2 Year | Biology | 500 |
| Harvard | 4 Year | Precalculus | 3000 |
| Harvard | 4 Year | Biology | 0 |

The actual dataset is much bigger, of course, and contains about 3,000 schools and 149 different disciplines. So I need to find all the 0's and then append the values to the dataframe.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could create these rows without writing over the sales I do have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to consider all the distinct combinations resulting from the cartesian product of the columns 'account', 'degree_type' and 'discipline'.

In that case, you can do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'account': {0: 'Harvard', 1: 'Yale', 2: 'Ivy Tech', 3: 'Harvard'},
 'degree_type': {0: '4 Year', 1: '4 Year', 2: '2 Year', 3: '4 Year'},
 'discipline': {0: 'Accounting', 1: 'Biology', 2: 'Biology', 3: 'Precalculus'},
 'dollars': {0: 1000, 1: 2000, 2: 500, 3: 3000}})

# get the unique values of each column 
idx_levels = {col: df[col].unique() for col in ['account', 'degree_type', 'discipline']}

# construct a new index from the cartesian product of those columns 
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx_levels.values(), names=idx_levels.keys())

# set those columns as the index and reindex the DataFrame to include all possible combinations
# set the 'dollars' of combinations not present in the original DataFrame to zero 
res = df.set_index(list(idx_levels)).reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

```
>>> df

    account degree_type   discipline  dollars
0   Harvard      4 Year   Accounting     1000
1      Yale      4 Year      Biology     2000
2  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology      500
3   Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus     3000

>>> res 

     account degree_type   discipline  dollars
0    Harvard      4 Year   Accounting     1000
1    Harvard      4 Year      Biology        0
2    Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus     3000
3    Harvard      2 Year   Accounting        0
4    Harvard      2 Year      Biology        0
5    Harvard      2 Year  Precalculus        0
6       Yale      4 Year   Accounting        0
7       Yale      4 Year      Biology     2000
8       Yale      4 Year  Precalculus        0
9       Yale      2 Year   Accounting        0
10      Yale      2 Year      Biology        0
11      Yale      2 Year  Precalculus        0
12  Ivy Tech      4 Year   Accounting        0
13  Ivy Tech      4 Year      Biology        0
14  Ivy Tech      4 Year  Precalculus        0
15  Ivy Tech      2 Year   Accounting        0
16  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology      500
17  Ivy Tech      2 Year  Precalculus        0
```

---

**If the DataFrame contains duplicates...**

Note that the above solution doesn't work if the DataFrame contains multiple entries with the same ('account', 'degree_type', 'discipline'). `reindex` can't handle duplicate indices.

In that case, we can take a different route and use `merge` instead.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'account': {0: 'Harvard', 1: 'Yale', 2: 'Ivy Tech', 3: 'Harvard'},
 'degree_type': {0: '4 Year', 1: '4 Year', 2: '2 Year', 3: '4 Year'},
 'discipline': {0: 'Accounting', 1: 'Biology', 2: 'Biology', 3: 'Precalculus'},
 'dollars': {0: 1000, 1: 2000, 2: 500, 3: 3000}})

# duplicate the DataFrame to simulate non-unique ('account', 'degree_type', 'discipline') combinations
df = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)

idx_levels = {col: df[col].unique() for col in ['account', 'degree_type', 'discipline']}

new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(idx_levels.values(), names=idx_levels.keys())

res = ( 
    df.merge(new_idx.to_series(name="idx"), 
             how='right', 
             on=list(idx_levels))
    .fillna(0)
    .drop(columns='idx')
)
```

```
>>> df

    account degree_type   discipline  dollars
0   Harvard      4 Year   Accounting     1000
1      Yale      4 Year      Biology     2000
2  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology      500
3   Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus     3000
4   Harvard      4 Year   Accounting     1000
5      Yale      4 Year      Biology     2000
6  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology      500
7   Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus     3000

# Note that the repeated entries are present in the result 
>>> res

     account degree_type   discipline  dollars
0    Harvard      4 Year   Accounting   1000.0
1    Harvard      4 Year   Accounting   1000.0
2    Harvard      4 Year      Biology      0.0
3    Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus   3000.0
4    Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus   3000.0
5    Harvard      2 Year   Accounting      0.0
6    Harvard      2 Year      Biology      0.0
7    Harvard      2 Year  Precalculus      0.0
8       Yale      4 Year   Accounting      0.0
9       Yale      4 Year      Biology   2000.0
10      Yale      4 Year      Biology   2000.0
11      Yale      4 Year  Precalculus      0.0
12      Yale      2 Year   Accounting      0.0
13      Yale      2 Year      Biology      0.0
14      Yale      2 Year  Precalculus      0.0
15  Ivy Tech      4 Year   Accounting      0.0
16  Ivy Tech      4 Year      Biology      0.0
17  Ivy Tech      4 Year  Precalculus      0.0
18  Ivy Tech      2 Year   Accounting      0.0
19  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology    500.0
20  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology    500.0
21  Ivy Tech      2 Year  Precalculus      0.0
```

Comment: @CIHAnalytics does it solve your issue?

Comment: Fantastic. Going to try it now! Also, your name "HarryPlotter" is just *chef's kiss*

Comment: @CIHAnalytics Hahah I'm glad to help ;) If the answer solves your issue feel free to mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting a an error for the last line that says "ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!" I've deduplicated the dataframe and only included the columns to match above. Any thoughts why that might the case?

Comment: @CIHAnalytics does your DataFrame contain duplicated ('account', 'degree_type', 'discipline') entries, is that it?

Comment: Hmmm, I've deduplicated the dataframe and it's still throwing the same error. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: @CIHAnalytics If I would take a guess you didn't specify the subset of columns to identify duplicates. I mean, `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['account', 'degree_type', 'discipline'])`.

Comment: You're a wizard, Harry Plotter! Answer accepted, you sexy beast you.

Comment: @CIHAnalytics Hahahah I love your attitude! No worries, I'm glad it worked!  Anyway, I've had another solution if you want to keep the duplicate combinations in the result. See if it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can `append`

```
out = df.append(pd.Series(['Harvard','4 Year','Biology',0],index=df.columns),ignore_index=True)
Out[49]: 
    account degree_type   discipline  dollars
0   Harvard      4 Year   Accounting     1000
1      Yale      4 Year      Biology     2000
2  Ivy Tech      2 Year      Biology      500
3   Harvard      4 Year  Precalculus     3000
4   Harvard      4 Year      Biology        0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue with appending is that there is about 3000 schools and 149 different disciplines, so I wouldn't be able to manually enter all of that in. Do you think maybe I could use this method with some sort of more automated way?

Comment: @CIHAnalytics where is all of that data? is it in your head? if so, you're going to have to type it out one way or another.

Comment: For all 3000 schools we've sold some product. For all 149 disciplines we've sold product. We just haven't sold all 149 disciplines to all 3000 schools. So in the example we've sold Biology to Yale, but not Harvard, but we have sold Accounting to Harvard, so that institution still exists even if we've never sold Biology to them.